# Conditionally disable shared library build

Tags: cygwin, autotools, autoconf, libtool

I’ve written [a C library that builds using Libtool](https://github.com/GaloisInc/ppamltracer), and I’d like to only build static libraries on Cygwin.  To that end, I placed

```
if test "$target_os" = "cygwin"; then
    AC_DISABLE_SHARED
fi
```

in my `configure.ac`.

This does indeed disable building shared libraries on Cygwin; however, it also disables building them everywhere else.  I assume this is because expanding `AC_DISABLE_SHARED` causes some unfortunate side effects.

How can I use Libtool to avoid building shared libraries on Cygwin while still building them on other platforms?

Comment: You should be able to `configure --disable-shared` on Cygwin (or any other platform) without any modifications to `configure.ac`.

Comment: Indeed, but I would like --disable-shared to be the default on Cygwin.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure `$target_os` is what you want. `$host_os` is the name for the system the code will run on. The 'target' triple is rarely used outside of building compilers / toolchains.

Even though the configure script might still say yes / enabled for shared libraries, you can override the result by setting the `enable_shared|static` variables.

```
AC_CANONICAL_HOST
...
LT_INIT

case $host_os in
  cygwin*)
    AC_MSG_RESULT([explicitly disabled shared libraries for $host])
    enable_shared=no; enable_static=yes ;;
esac
```

These variables aren't documented, so it's *technically* a hack - but it's basically behaving like any other `AC_ARG_ENABLE` option. Your original idea might still work if it appears before `LT_INIT`, but this approach overrides any configure options.